# Add alert box after procces is successful

Tags: javascript, php, curl, popup

I have this PHP cURL code. I know this is a simple question. I just want to have an alert box right after the process is done but I don't know where to put my code and its right format. Can someone help?

```
function myFunction() {
    alert("Successfull!");
}
```

PHP

```
<?php
  $account = $_POST["selectbasic-0"];
  $sitename = $_POST["siteAlias"];


  //Initiate cURL 
  $ch = curl_init();
  //Set cURL parameters
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, '');
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/json',       
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data))                                                                
  ); 

  $output = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

if your output variable returns 1 (true) then you can try this.

```
 if($output) {
       echo "<script>";
       echo "alert(""\Successfull!\");";
       echo "</script>";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your php is a server side script. You can't call javascript functions from server. You could 
    `echo 'success';` 
or 
    `echo '<script>alert("success");</script>';`
after curl_exec function which returns true or false.